# Latitude and Longitude keep changing every time I convert from Degrees Minutes Seconds to Decimal Degrees in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, math

If I enter the a location of:

Latitude = 28 Degrees, 45 Minutes, 12 Seconds
Longitude = 81 Degrees, 39 Minutes, 32.4 Seconds

It gets converted into Decimal Degrees format to be stored in the database with the following code:

```
Coordinates coordinates = new Coordinates();
coordinates.LatitudeDirection = this.radLatNorth.Checked ? Coordinates.Direction.North : Coordinates.Direction.South;
coordinates.LatitudeDegree = this.ConvertDouble(this.txtLatDegree.Text);
coordinates.LatitudeMinute = this.ConvertDouble(this.txtLatMinute.Text);
coordinates.LatitudeSecond = this.ConvertDouble(this.txtLatSecond.Text);
coordinates.LongitudeDirection = radLongEast.Checked ? Coordinates.Direction.East :     Coordinates.Direction.West; 
coordinates.LongitudeDegree = this.ConvertDouble(this.txtLongDegree.Text);
coordinates.LongitudeMinute = this.ConvertDouble(this.txtLongMinute.Text);
coordinates.LongitudeSecond = this.ConvertDouble(this.txtLongSecond.Text);
//gets the calulated fields of Lat and Long
coordinates.ConvertDegreesMinutesSeconds();
```

In the above code, ConvertDouble is defined as:

```
  private double ConvertDouble(string value)
  {
        double newValue = 0;
        double.TryParse(value, out newValue);

        return newValue;
  }
```

and ConvertDegreesMinutesSeconds is defined as:

```
public void ConvertDegreesMinutesSeconds()
{
    this.Latitude = this.LatitudeDegree + (this.LatitudeMinute / 60) + (this.LatitudeSecond / 3600);
        this.Longitude = this.LongitudeDegree + (this.LongitudeMinute / 60) + (this.LongitudeSecond / 3600);

        //adds the negative sign
        if (LatitudeDirection == Direction.South)
        {
            this.Latitude = 0 - this.Latitude;

        }
        else if (LongitudeDirection == Direction.West)
        {
            this.Longitude = 0 - this.Longitude;
        }
    }
```

If I don't make any change to the latitude or longitude and I click Apply Changes which basically does the above calucation again, it generates a different latitude and longitude in the database.  This happens every time I go to edit it and don't make a change (I just click Apply Changes and it does the calculation again with a different result).

In the above scenario, the new Latitude and Longitude is:

Latitude = 28 Degrees, 45 Minutes, 12 Seconds
Longitude = 81 Degrees, 40 Minutes, 32.4 Seconds

If I do it again, it becomes:

Latitude = 28 Degrees, 45 Minutes, 12 Seconds
Longitude = 81 Degrees, 41 Minutes, 32.4 Seconds

The other part of this is that when I go into edit, it takes the decimal degrees format of the latitude and longitude and converts it to the degrees minutes seconds format and puts them into their respective textboxes.  The code for that is:

```
public void SetFields()
{
    Coordinates coordinateLocation = new Coordinates();
    coordinateLocation.Latitude = this.Latitude;
    coordinateLocation.Longitude = this.Longitude;
    coordinateLocation.ConvertDecimal();

    this.radLatNorth.Checked =
        coordinateLocation.LatitudeDirection == Coordinates.Direction.North;
    this.radLatSouth.Checked = !this.radLatNorth.Checked;
    this.txtLatDegree.Text = coordinateLocation.LatitudeDegree.ToString().Replace("-", string.Empty);
    this.txtLatMinute.Text = Math.Round(coordinateLocation.LatitudeMinute, 0).ToString().Replace("-", string.Empty);
    this.txtLatSecond.Text = Math.Round(coordinateLocation.LatitudeSecond, 2).ToString().Replace("-", string.Empty);

    this.radLongEast.Checked =
        coordinateLocation.LongitudeDirection == Coordinates.Direction.East;
    this.radLongWest.Checked = !this.radLongEast.Checked;
    this.txtLongDegree.Text = coordinateLocation.LongitudeDegree.ToString().Replace("-", string.Empty); ;
    this.txtLongMinute.Text = Math.Round(coordinateLocation.LongitudeMinute, 0).ToString().Replace("-", string.Empty);
    this.txtLongSecond.Text = Math.Round(coordinateLocation.LongitudeSecond, 2).ToString().Replace("-", string.Empty);
}
```

From the above examples, you can see that the Minute kept increasing by 1, which would indicate why it is generating a different latitude and longitude in decimal degrees in the database, so I guess the problem is more in the above area, but I am not sure where or why it is doing it?

```
  public void ConvertDecimal()
    {
        this.LatitudeDirection = this.Latitude > 0 ? Direction.North : Direction.South;
        this.LatitudeDegree = (int)Math.Truncate(this.Latitude);
        if (LatitudeDirection == Direction.South)
        {
            this.LatitudeDegree = 0 - this.LatitudeDegree;
        }            
        this.LatitudeMinute = (this.Latitude - Math.Truncate(this.Latitude)) * 60;
        this.LatitudeSecond = (this.LatitudeMinute - Math.Truncate(this.LatitudeMinute)) * 60;

        this.LongitudeDirection = this.Longitude > 0 ? Direction.East : Direction.West;
        this.LongitudeDegree = (int)Math.Truncate(this.Longitude);            
        if (LongitudeDirection == Direction.West)
        {
            this.LongitudeDegree = 0 - this.LongitudeDegree;
        }            
        this.LongitudeMinute = (this.Longitude - Math.Truncate(this.Longitude)) * 60;
        this.LongitudeSecond = (this.LongitudeMinute - Math.Truncate(this.LongitudeMinute)) * 60;
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the CoordinateLocation.ConvertDecimal code?

Comment: ConvertDecimal code is posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to truncate your Minutes (maybe Seconds too, I'm not sure) rather than round.  Note that the Math.Round used below is just to get the Minutes/Seconds components to the desired number of significant digits.

```
double Minutes(double decimalDegrees)
{
  //Get hours
  double h = Math.Truncate(lat);
  //Get minutes + seconds
  double x = (Math.Abs(h - Math.Round(lat, 12)) * 60.0);
  //Everything after the decimal is seconds
  double min = Math.Truncate(x);
  return min;
}
```

I based this conversion code on this codeplex project: http://geoframework.codeplex.com/
Look in Latitude class.

Comment: Thanks, this appeared to fix it so far.  I am not sure if this is possible, but would someone enter something like 30.42 minutes.  If they do, then truncate would not work.

Comment: @Xaisoft It seems to me like minutes would always be an integer value. If someone wants to enter 30.42 minutes, wouldn't that be the same as 30 minutes and .42 * 60 seconds?

Comment: you are correct, forgive me, I am new to this, plus I am not the one doing the entering so who knows how people would enter it.  Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: By the way, I just changed the Math.Round for minutes in the SetFields method to Math.Truncate and that seemed to work.  I left Math.Round for seconds because I don't want to actually truncate it because they can enter values like 30.42 or 30.12 for example

Answer (score 1):

You're rounding your minutes and seconds when displaying them instead of truncating them or using Math.Floor.  Since you have over 30 seconds, your minutes has a fractional value over 0.5 so it rounds up.